# Why can't I create Tree using the code below?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

It's a function to bulid a binary tree,but it can't work,can someone tell me what's wrong with my code

```
typedef struct treeNode* BT;
struct treeNode {
    int val;
    treeNode* left;
    treeNode* right;
};
BT createTree(BT root) {
    int data = 0;
    cin >> data;
    if (data == -1) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    root = new treeNode;
    root->val = data;
    createTree(root->left);
    createTree(root->right);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: ```void preOrder(BT root) {
 if (root) {
  cout << root->val << " ";
  preOrder(root->left);
  preOrder(root->right);
 }
 
}
int main() {
 BT root=nullptr;
 root = createTree(root);
 preOrder(root);
 return 0;
}```

Comment: what's the output and what's the expected output?

Comment: FYI, in C++ you don't need `typedef struct`.  Just use the name of the struct to create instances and pointers.

Comment: thanks a lot,I know C++ can use struct pointre directly,but i think its more convenient this way using typedef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring the result of `createTree(root->left);` and `createTree(root->right);`
What's more, in your implementation the argument `root` is meaningless. You're not using it at all. Code below should work.

```
BT createTree() {
    int data = 0;
    BT root;
    cin >> data;
    if (data == -1) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    root = new treeNode;
    root->val = data;
    root->left = createTree();
    root->right = createTree();
    return root;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,i now finallly understand